# Today's Date in Phonegap iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm trying to get today's date inside of a Phonegap app on iOS using the Date(); function. It works just fine in web browsers and gives an output, but when compiled in Phonegap it gives no output.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} today = yyyy+mm+dd;
document.write(today);
```

In a browser it gives the proper output for today, 20130115, but in both emulator and hardware testing i get no output

Comment: For day-of-month and month both greater than 9 your expression for "today" will be interpreted numerically.

Comment: That's fine, that's not an issue. More just concerned about getting the variable to actually write out something

Answer (score 0):

```
var todayDate = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

This code will successfully give you today's date.

You can use that code for manipulating the date formate as per your specification.